# Error while installing driver for rtl8723de from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

Tags: drivers

I followed following steps to install WiFi driver for rtl8723de:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

I am facing following issue:

```
$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.3.0-59-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-5.3.0-59-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

Kindly help!

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Headers are not installed for some reason. But it depends on the release how to fix it properly.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 19.10
Release: 19.10
Codename: eoan

Comment: Then `sudo apt install linux-generic` should solve it.

Comment: It is already installed and most updated. The error still persists.

Comment: Is `linux-headers-5.3.0-59-generic` installed?

Comment: 5.3.0-59.53 is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de is the new link for installing driver. Earlier link is obsolete now.

Just follow the instruction and WiFi will work as charm.

Regards,
Gargi

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

Next, try to install the wireless driver again.

Comment: If it is 18.04, then it is not correct.

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 19.10
Release: 19.10
Codename: eoan